# jQuery dialog is not opening on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am giving the codes in which link inside gridview1 do not work after closing it once

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialogOptions = {
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "#dialogContainer",
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        title: "Dialog Title",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        show: { effect: "fold", duration: 4000 },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }

    };
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {
        $("div:ui-dialog:visible").dialog("close");
    });
    $( function() {
        $(".dialog-marker").on("click", function () {

            var d = $(this).next("div").first().dialog(dialogOptions);
            d.dialog("open");
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

My aspx page code is

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="width: 400px;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      DataKeyNames="BusNo"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RouteName" HeaderText="RouteName" SortExpression="RouteName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="divButton" runat="server" class="btn_styling dialog-marker" title="This could also have been a <button> element or maybe an <img> element...anything really">X</div>
            <div id="popup" style="display: none;">
              <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="StopName" HeaderText="StopName" SortExpression="StopName" />

                </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT StopName from BusStops WHERE (BusNo = @BusNo)">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="BusNo" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      <RowStyle BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT BusNo,RouteName from BusRoutes">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </div>
  <div id="dialogContainer">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
and code behind code is  

 public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        GridView gv2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
        SqlDataSource sds = (SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource2");

        sds.SelectParameters["BusNo"].DefaultValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        gv2.DataBind();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may work,

```
$(document).off("click", ".dialog-marker").on("click", ".dialog-marker", function () {
    var d = $(this).next("div").first().dialog(dialogOptions);
    d.dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. ***When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed.***

You may refer http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

Please add  `$(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {` inside `document.ready` . Some thing like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {
          $("div:ui-dialog:visible").dialog("close");
       });
       $(".dialog-marker").on("click", function () {

           var d = $(this).next("div").first().dialog(dialogOptions);
           d.dialog("open");
          return false;
        });

    });
```

Or simply

make a funtion like this and add a function call on `onClick` event

```
function showDialogBox(){
     var d = $(this).next("div").first().dialog(dialogOptions);
        d.dialog("open");
        return false;
}


function closeDialogBox(){
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {
        $("div:ui-dialog:visible").dialog("close");
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the link not working after working once.button is not working on second click.